# Can I retry DKIM domain verification in AWS through API or some other automated way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, dkim

I have a small .net core console app that does a variety of setup for customer domains. Part of that process is to retrieve tokens from AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.VerifyDomainDkim using .net SDK. This info is then forwarded to the customer side, who often do not get the CNAME records written within the 72 hour window.

Looking at this in the web console for AWS, Under Amazon SES->Configuration, Identity Status is labeled Unverified and in the Authentication tab and the DKIM section there is a Retry button.
**So what I really need is a way to automate that retry**, for a given set of DKIM tokens (I do not want to regenerate them because of customer reason above). Initial searches through AWS docs have yielded nothing, nor has the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem completely, but I've got similar problem, though I'm using *SimpleEmailV2* library and its `CreateEmailIdentity` and `GetEmailIdentity` methods in the first place.
After some trial and error I noticed that calling `VerifyDomainDkim` method from older *SimpleEmail* library restarts the verification process, preserving previously generated DKIM records.

This is how I do this in my code (*response* is the result of the `GetEmailIdentity` method call from *SimpleEmailV2* library):

```
if (response.DkimAttributes.Status == DkimStatus.FAILED)
{
    var clientv1 = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(
        Settings.AwsAccessKeyId,
        Settings.AwsAccessPassword, 
        GetRegionEndpoint(serverRegion));

    clientv1.VerifyDomainDkim(
        new Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model.VerifyDomainDkimRequest()
        {
            Domain = domainName
        }
    );
}
```